# visualforce extension override save method throws an error

Tags: visualforce

From visual force page I am trying to save values of selected field on click even of button called add. below is the code of visual force page

```visualforce
<apex:page id="thePage" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Extension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Rent" collapsible="false" id="Rent" rendered="{!NOT(readOnly)}" >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Type" for="Type" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Type__c}" id="Type" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Table" />
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Add" for="Calc" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Calculate__c}" id="Calc" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!Add}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </<apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:page>
```

and Extension for the above page is as follows.

```apex
public Opportunity opp { get;set; }

public PageReference add(){

    List<Opportunity> opps;
    ApexPages.StandardController stdCont;
    String oppid = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    System.debug('opp id = ' + oppid ); 

    if (oppId != null || oppId != ''){
        LAId = oppid;
    }

    System.debug('ID = ' + LAId );   
    opps = [select id,Type__c,Calculate__c 
            from Opportunity 
            where id = :LAId and Type__c != null];

    if (opps.size() > 0){
        opp = opps[0];
    }

    insert opp;
}
```

I am receiving following error when I click on Add Button

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 006q0000006INdQAAW;
>   first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an
>   insert call: [Id]

I am very new to this and I have never overridden standard save method before so I apologies in advance if I am asking very basic thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The record already has an id as you just queried for it.

Not sure why you are trying to insert it directly after you got it from the database.

But instead of `insert` use `upsert`.

In addition when you set this:

```apex
if (opps.size() > 0){
    opp = opps[0];
}
```

You are overwriting `opp` that is set in your Visualforce with the values you have just queried. You do not need to query the record that you already have from your VF page. So you are basically just throwing away any changes a user would have made on your page.

Comment: hey I am trying to update fields Type__c and calculate__c and only querying Id to match in SOQL record id = :oppid . 

I have replaced insert with upsert and it has inserted it once and started giving error from next time.

Comment: @Ricky Without seeing your VF page I am unsure, but I have updated my answer with what I think your main problem is.

Comment: All I am trying to achieve is save the value of those to fields on Standard Object Fields. May be querying those fields are not right method. What else could be the solution to it? I just want to store those fields.

Comment: @Ricky Since this answered the original question and you have asked another about the secondary issue, please mark this as resolved/answered.

Comment: I just marked this as an answer to my first problem. I would appreciate if you can help me with the other issue that I realize is the actual issue.  Thanks is advance