# How to save fields from visual force page with extension as controller

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I am trying to save value user select on picklist field to Opportunity object field. my visual force page is as follows.

```apex
<apex:page id="thePage" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Extension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Rent" collapsible="false" id="Rent" rendered="{!NOT(readOnly)}" >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Type" for="Type" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Type__c}" id="Type" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Table" />
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Add" for="Calc" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Calculate__c}" id="Calc" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!Add}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </<apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:page>
```

and extension is as follows

```apex
public class Extension {
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;
    public Opportunity  la   {get;set;}
    private String  laId;

    /* Contstructor */
    public Extension(ApexPages.StandardController stdCont) 
    {
       this.laId = stdCont.getId();

       stdCtrl = stdCont;

    }

     public PageReference Add()
     {
        return stdCtrl.save();
     }
}
```

it does not give any error but not insert or update field value. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but, I'm not sure I understand the question. What are you expecting to happen that's not happening?

Comment: @sfdcfox  As I am using extension with standardcontroller on my Visual force page, I have to override Save() . So from visual force page when user click on Add button I want to store thise two fields on Opportunity fields. Currently it is only displaying there and not storing user input.

Comment: I do not see any code in your `Add()` method. If you are asking about trouble with that method it would be advisable to show the code you are actually having trouble with. Otherwise the answer is: Write the code in the Add method to update the record. It addition the page will not compile as there is no property named `opp` in the extension.

Comment: for reference for those of you trying to help:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114796/visualforce-extension-override-save-method-throws-an-error/114801?noredirect=1#comment160818_114801

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The record you receive in your constructor is where the changes made by the user will appear. In the other question, you query the record back from the database, thus ignoring the user's input. Ideally, your extension should look like this:

```
public class Extension {
    ApexPages.StandardController c;
    public Extension(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
        c = ctrl;
    }
    public PageReference add() {
        return c.save();  // Saves user input
    }
}
```

If you need to manipulate data around before saving, you can do so by modifying the record contained in the StandardController:

```
public PageReference add() {
    Opportunity o = (Opportunity)c.getRecord();
    o.Name = someNewValue();
    return c.save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't required to manipulate data. I only want to store user input. So I have tried your first solution. But that doesn't work.  those fields on my Detail screen page is still showing no value.

Comment: @Ricky I just noticed that you're binding to the variable you got from the standard controller. I expect this might be a race condition of sorts. Try changing `{!opp` to `{!Opportunity` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get you . where do I have to replace {!opp with {!opportunity ?

Comment: Ohh I got it, You meant on visual force page? Let me try that quickly,.

Comment: I have changed that to  {!Opportunity on my visaul force page that still doesn't store values.

Comment: @Ricky Can you update your question's code, so we can see what's going on? What you're trying to do is incredibly mundane and should work without too much effort.

Comment: yes I have updated question now.

Comment: @Ricky That's pretty textbook code alright. The only other thing I can think of is if you have any validation rules, etc that are failing. Try adding an `apex:pagemessages` element to your page and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Yup I was actually thinking same. yup I am getting this error messge as well .Basically in the same controller I have If else condition to check those two fields are not blank . and in else part I have added validation message now.  It is throwing me an error. As it is thinking those fields are not holding values. This happend after I changed from {!opp to {!opprtunity. I have tested this by changing the it back to {!opp and it is not throwing that error.

Comment: @Ricky I still suspect that the code in your question isn't what you actually have. For starters, there's no form (I just noticed), which means the page shouldn't compile as is. I do know that you've got some wires crossed in your code, because if you were using the standard controller correctly, it would work correctly. Somehow, you've disassociated the user input by way of some duplicate variable or something. I'm not sure how else we can help you without getting that sorted out. In fact, given what you're doing, I don't even know why you have an extension at this point.

Comment: hey can you come on chat, where I can show and explain what exactly I am doing

Comment: Infact I don'i Mind putting my entire page and controller here. but that wil be confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37192/discussion-between-sfdcfox-and-ricky).

Comment: Thanks for this simple explantion about the difference between getting the record values from the VF Page vs getting it from the database. This should be somewhere in the official documentation.